# How to listen for Ctrl-P key press in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser

I want to disable print for some webpages.
How to wireup cross browser hotkeys (Cntrl + P) to a javascript that will be fired whenever hotkeys are pressed?

Comment: What if the user does file > print?

Comment: @ScottE OP never mentions that as his intention

Comment: @charlieg OP states "I want to disable print for some webpages."

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Although you _can_ catch `ctrl+p`, it is not possible to prevent a user from printing your page., Whether that's by disabling JS on the page, using their browser's console to override your binding, using a browser plugin that prints it regardless of what you catch, by stitching together a bunch of screenshots, or a physical camera, **if the user's eyes can see your content, the user can create a physical copy of your content. Period.**

If you're actually looking at how to keep someone from stealing your content, look into DRM and how to secure your IP rights.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can override by capturing the event.

```
jQuery(document).bind("keyup keydown", function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This works.  FYI, we're trying to override default print keys and learned that Mac's Command key has different `keyCode` values in each browser which get handled by the the libraries below.

Comment: should be

 `$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {

        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 80) {

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    });`

Answer (score 4):

Also a great library is [Mousetrap](http://www.github.com/ccampbell/mousetrap)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Keyboard Shortcuts Library](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/).

Instead of just copy pasting it let's havea  look at the source and understand how it works.

You can see [the source here](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js)